# Не могу зафиксировать шапку

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть [страница](http://new-live.kz/pages/view/nauchnye_trudy)

Есть шапка с такой версткой

```
<div class="fixed_header">
  <div class="grey" style=" background-color:#f8f8f8; opacity:1;">
  </div>
</div>
```

style

```
.fixed_header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999; /* Любое положительное значение */
}
```

Но контентная часть не хочет идти после шапки. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что блок `.fixed_header` находится не в потоке документа, из-за этого идет смещение контентной части. Для решения проблемы блок `.fixed_header` нужно обернуть еще в один и задать ему фиксированную высоту, чтобы он занимал пространство, отведенной для `.fixed_header`:

```
<div class="header"> 
    <div class="fixed_header">
        <div class="grey"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.header {
   height: 217px; /* Высота вашего фиксированного хедера */
}
```

Также можно непосредственно самой контентной части задать смещение через `margin`, однако первый вариант более верный, потому что рассчитан на то, что хедера может вообще не быть или он может изменяться.

Comment: Не согласен с "*первый вариант более верный, потому что рассчитан на то, что хедера может вообще не быть или он может изменяться.*". Эквивалентные варианты, так как в первом случае придётся менять или удалять `height`, а во втором — `margin-top`.  Только во втором случае не придётся оборачивать в `header`.

Comment: Просто при первом варианте можно убрать хедер вместе с оберткой, а вот при втором нужно будет не тольк убирать хедер, но и как-то перебивать стили к основному контенту.

Comment: При втором варианте просто убрать `margin-top` и всё (если контент в одном блоке). Конечно, зависит от разметки.